# Problema al cortar nombre de cadena en Bash dentro de un ciclo

Tags: linux, bash

Tengo 29 videos en una carpeta y les extraigo a cada uno el audio con ffmpeg. Los videos se llaman *video.webm* y a los audios los nombro *audio.ogg*. Uso {%????} para quitar los últimos 4 caracteres del nombre de cada video (la extensión) y les añado la extensión de audio vorbis, como se aprecia en el código.

Mi problema es que en la segunda iteración me corta **los primeros 4 caracteres** del nombre del segundo video y por ende ffmpeg no lo encuentra para procesarlo. Este corte solo pasa con los archivos pares, no con los nones. ¿Cómo evitarlo?

El código es el siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash

find * -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file

do
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -c copy -map 0:1 "${file%????}"ogg
done
```

Comment: necesitaríamos un listado de nombres para poder replicar el error

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución:

ffmpeg lee de stdin, por lo tanto, consume la entrada destinada a `while read`. Solo hay que redirigir stdin agregando < /dev/null

`ffmpeg -i "$file" -c copy -map 0:1 "${file%????}"ogg < /dev/null`

Comment: Recuerda que puedes "aceptar" tu propia respuesta :)